# Can't import random.randint

Tags: python, import

In python console I can run:

```
from random import randint
```

But I get an error when I run:

```
import random.randint
```

The error says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'random.randint'; 'random' is not a package
```

I thought the two import statements were synonymous. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import random.randint` is parsed as the import of a *submodule* named `randint` from a *package* named `random`.

The error message is trying to tell you that `random` is not a package with a submodule. In fact it's just a single module, [`random.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py), and `randint` is a method defined in that module.

You may use this:

```
from random import randint
randint(...)
```

Or this:

```
import random
random.randint(...)
```

Comment: Yea so submodule and method are two different things defined in a package